# JS Onload Works In One Instance But Not Another

Tags: javascript

I have this code that displays a regular clock and an octal clock by ID. It works if I just have 1 of each clock on a page (just use each ID once), but if I have more than 1 of each clock (use each ID more than once) then the latter clocks won't work. What might be inhibiting the latter clocks from working?

JS:

```
function checkTime(i) {
    'use strict';
    if (i < 10) {
        i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
}
function a() {
    'use strict';
    var oct = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"],
        octtime,
        oct1,
        oct2,
        oct3,
        oct4,
        oct5,
        oct6,
        octvalue,
        point = ".",
        now = new Date(),
        hours = now.getHours(),
        minutes = now.getMinutes(),
        seconds = now.getSeconds(),
        h = checkTime(hours),
        m = checkTime(minutes),
        s = checkTime(seconds),
        totsecs = [hours * 3600 + minutes * 60 + seconds + (now.getTime() % 1000) / 1000];
    octtime = Math.floor(totsecs / (86400 / 262144));
    oct1 = Math.floor(octtime / 32768);
    octtime -= 32768 * oct1;
    oct2 = Math.floor(octtime / 4096);
    octtime -= 4096 * oct2;
    oct3 = Math.floor(octtime / 512);
    octtime -= 512 * oct3;
    oct4 = Math.floor(octtime / 64);
    octtime -= 64 * oct4;
    oct5 = Math.floor(octtime / 8);
    octtime -= 8 * oct5;
    oct6 = octtime;
    octvalue = point + oct[oct1] + oct[oct2] + oct[oct3] + oct[oct4] + oct[oct5] + oct[oct6];
    document.getElementById('j').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    document.getElementById('k').innerHTML = octvalue;
    window.setTimeout(a);
}
window.onload = a;
```

Test page: http://www.gloryhood.com/articles/zztest.html

Comment: The test page returns `403 - Forbidden`

Comment: You use an ID more than once. IDs have to be unique.

Comment: You need to reference each of your clocks and set the `innerHTML` to what you want for each clock. You can either create different `id`'s for the clocks or you can try using one `class` and do something like `getElementsByClassName()` and loop through each, but you will need a way to identify each clock. One way is to use their index because they are sorted as they appear in the source code.

Comment: @boombox In the JS I changed the getElementById to getElementsByClassName and in the HTML I changed the id= to class= but it didn't work. Why is that?